# how to solve "302 found" response after form submit in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-302

I am working on codeigniter, i have a login view where i submit form to a controller for login  functionality, but the response i get is a 302 Found, and redirects to my login page.

my controller code is

```
class super_admin extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/login_view');
    }

    function checkLogin()
    {
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pwd']);

        $this->load->model('admin/admin_model');
        $user = $this->admin_model->checkUser($email);
        //print_r($user[0]);
        if ($user && ($user[0]->password == md5($pwd)))
        {

            $user_data = array(
                            'user_id' => $user[0]->user_id,
                            'user_name' => $user[0]->name,
                            'user_email' => $user[0]->email
                        );

            $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
            $this->load->view('admin/dashboard_view',$user_data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('invalid', '<div class="alert alert-error" id="invalid" ><h6>Invalid Email or Password</h6></div>');
            redirect('admin/super_admin');
        }
    }
}
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: You don't need to do `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);` just use `$this->input->post('email', true)` check input class (documentation)[http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html].

Comment: tried it, still the same 302..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not load the view in methods where you submit your forms use redirects otherwise you do not get the post requests when you refresh your page and your condition returns false which will cause malfunctioning. Try this workaround. Also check what your $user variable conatins.

```
class super_admin extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/login_view');
    }

    function checkLogin()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email', TRUE);
        $pwd = $this->input->post('pwd', TRUE);

        $this->load->model('admin/admin_model');
        $user = $this->admin_model->checkUser($email);
        //print_r($user[0]);
        if ($user && ($user[0]->password == md5($pwd)))
        {

            $user_data = array(
                            'user_id' => $user[0]->user_id,
                            'user_name' => $user[0]->name,
                            'user_email' => $user[0]->email
                        );

            $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
            redirect('super_admin/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('invalid', '<div class="alert alert-error" id="invalid" ><h6>Invalid Email or Password</h6></div>');
            redirect('admin/super_admin');
        }
    }

    function dashboard()
    {
       if( $this->session->userdata('user_id') ) {
         $user_data = $this->session->all_userdata();
         $this->load->view('admin/dashboard_view',$user_data);
       } else {
         redirect('admin/super_admin');
       }
    }
}
```