# codeigniter 302 found error

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-302

I have tried everything and I am close to giving up. Help please.

I've been trying to get rid of the index.php in codeigniter and have done every code that google has provided to put in the .htaccess.

Currently, I have this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and this does work, but every time I submit a form, I get back this wonderful 302 error that is driving me crazy.

[image: 302 error]

one of my submit function in my controller...the others are basically the same for other forms. I have already tried the refresh and the location method of redirecting, neither change anything. I do not believe this is the issue.

```
public function submitStory(){
  if (empty($this->user)) {
    redirect('/home/');
  }else{
    $this->story_model->writeStory();
     redirect('story/newChapterView/');
  }
```

}

my model is just inserting into the database

```
public function writeStory(){
  $this->title = strip_tags($this->input->post('wTitle'));  
  $this->date = time();
  $this->author = strip_tags($this->input->post('wAuthor'));    
  $this->type = strip_tags($this->input->post('wType'));    
  $this->db->insert('story_tbl', $this);
}
```

one of my forms, their pretty much just a standard codeigniter form

```
<?=form_open('story/submitStory', array('id' => 'newStory'));?>
    <p class="textBox"><label>Story Title: </label><input id="storyTitle" type="text" name="wTitle" autocomplete="off"  /></p>
    <p><label>Complete:</label><select class="drop" name="wcomplete" id="complete"><option value="no">no</option><option value="yes">yes</option></select></p>
    <p><label>Description:&nbsp;</label><textarea name="wDescription" id="wDescription" class="wDescription"></textarea><span id="discWarn">500 characters left</span></p>
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit Details" /></p>    
</form>
```

Comment: You are assuming the issue is with the redirect - but if it only happens with forms, maybe check them? What is the HTML generated for the form? What URL is it being posted to?

Comment: I added one of my forms above. What do you mean by the URL it's being posted to?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If it doesn't help then you should check mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: this one gives me 404's on redirect and when refreshed a 302 error. How do I check to see if mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: print_r( apache_get_modules() );

Comment: then try phpinfo(); it also shows list of modules. I think you have installed CGI/FastCGi rather then apachehandler

Comment: there are no modules listed and no sign of mod_rewrite. Is this an issue with my host or can I somehow enable it? And it says I do have CGI/FastCGI.

Comment: enable mod_rewrite is a must.

Comment: How do I enable it? I have never run into this problem before, I have never had it disabled before if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If I do then I get back "No input file specified."

Comment: Obviously, something is wrong. Are you putting it in the right htaccess? In the same directory as index.php, system and applications dirs.

Comment: I am putting it in the right spot. It's driving me crazy, because I have done this more than a few times and the code I used for those projects just isn't working on this one. I'm starting to think it's an apache issue because of the header output I'm getting back.

Comment: Is this a server or your local device? Can you provide a URL? Also this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559187/how-to-solve-302-found-response-after-form-submit-in-codeigniter

Comment: I'm hosting it over on ipage. The URL is www.writeyourfiction.com and the 302 is mainly rearing it's ugly head after you hit logout

Answer (score 0):

try something like this for your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The `?` after `index.php` helps to fix `'No input file specified'` error

Comment: This works, but it's still displaying server information when I submit forms. http://i1280.photobucket.com/albums/a485/Jessica_Sears/ScreenShot2013-06-09at84957AM_zps62049791.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I have the same code in `.htaccess` file and it works without any problem.

As you are saying it occurs with form submit, probably the problem is with your server configuration. Recheck your server configuration.

Comment: Are you talking about the configuration within the codeigniter folder or the server itself ipage?

Comment: I am talking about the server itself.

Comment: I've talked with the people at ipage and they say everything is fine. I don't have access to anything else other than that.

Comment: Have you changed `$config['index_page']` and `config['base_url']` in your `config` file properly? You should also post your form submit code and error log if possible.

Comment: I have changed the config properties. I'll post my submit function above, and I've turned my error log up, but it's not producing anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to replace

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

with....

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And on all lines that have this line....change to...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [PT, L]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have already done the first step, and unfortunitly that rewriteRule sends me a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could fix your problem.

```
public function submitStory(){
  if (empty($this->user)) {
    redirect('/home/', 'location', 301);
  }else{
    $this->story_model->writeStory();
    redirect('story/newChapterView/', 'location', 301);
  }
}
```

redirect() function is look like this

```
redirect ($url, $method = 'location', $response = 302) {...};
```

**The default Response Code  is 302**. So you must to change it manually.

**p.s.** The third parameter is only available with **'location'** redirects, and **not 'refresh'**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunitly, I'm still getting this header back. http://s1280.photobucket.com/user/Jessica_Sears/media/ScreenShot2013-06-09at84957AM_zps62049791.jpg.html

Answer (score 0):

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
to
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. 
Just replace 
    $config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
    by
    $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"

HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have already done this step. This is what is causing my issue.